# does jQuery stop() work on custom functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are three images that I have made a tooltip for each.
I wanted to show tooltips within timed intervals say for 2 seconds first tooltip shows and for the second interval the 2nd tooltips fades in and so on.

for example it can be done with this function

```
function cycle(id) {
    var nextId = (id == "block1") ? "block2": "block1";
    $("#" + id)
        .delay(shortIntervalTime)
        .fadeIn(500)
        .delay(longIntervalTime)
        .fadeOut(500, function() {cycle(nextId)});
}
```

now what i want is to stop the cycle function when moseover action occurs on each of the images and show the corresponding tooltip. And again when the mouse went away again the cycle function fires.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand everthing correctly, than try this code. Tt stops the proccess if you hover the image and continues if you leave the image. The stop() function will work on custom functions if you implement them like the fadeOut(), slideIn(), ... functions of jquery.

```
  $('#' + id)
.fadeIn(500, function () {
   var img = $(this).find('img'),
       self = $(this),
       fadeOut = true;

   img.hover(function () {
                fadeOut = false;                    
            }, 
            function () {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    self.fadeOut(500);
                }, 2000);
            }
      );

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        if (fadeOut === false) {
            return;
        }
        self.fadeOut(500);
    }, 2000);
});​
```